# How to pass data from Swift file to SwiftUI file

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to pass the `variable` `TeamOne2` (right file) from the file which is created with `UIKit` to the file which is created with `SwiftUI` (left file). How can I do that? `Struct.Variable` does not work.
The reason is that I created my app with `Storyboard` and `UIKit` and want to use the `Widget` which comes with `iOS 14`. But I cannot rewrite my code to `SwiftUI` because I just want to use the `Widget`.

[Xcode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r2oS.jpg)

Comment: You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so we can give you better feedback. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried nothing because I haven't found any information online. There are tutorials how you can pass a variable from SwiftUI to UIKit but i found nothing about from UIKit to SwiftUI.

Comment: This is a basic development pattern issue and you should to research on what MVVM is and how it works. But in short you need a "ViewModel" or a "Manager" that will hold/manage your data from DataenHolen2. Once your data has a home your can open a new instance or a shared instance that connects with both UIKit and SwiftUI.

Comment: Consider UIKit and SwiftUI like 2 pieces of paper (View) and you are the Manager that holds and stores the data. If I give you a pen (ViewModel) you can write onto either piece of paper. This explanation might just make it worse but there is no easy way to make this connection. Try the Apple SwiftUI tutorial in Handing User Input https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

Comment: Is this for school? Are you using MVC? If so, you might be using the term UIKit wrong. Your JSON data is being decoded to Swift (language). UIKit and SwiftUI are Frameworks written in Swift/ObjectiveC. UIKit uses Storyboards that use ViewControllers - How does your ViewController (used by your Storyboard) access the data? a SwiftUI `ObservableObject`(ViewModel) should be able to access the data in the same way. Then just connect your Widget with an `ObservedObject` like the tutorial.